# How to compare the column values of two last inserted specified rows on the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, automated-tests

I have a data set that is being updated on each operation maden by customers. 
For example, I am getting a customer's last two operations by

```
select id, 
       referance 
from (select id, 
             referance, 
             row_number() 
             over (order by time desc) as seqnum 
      from mytable where id=':id') 
al where seqnum <= 2
```

where `id` is getting from a feature file. But now I need to compare the referance values of these two operations.

mytable:

```
id  | name  | referance  |   time   |
-------------------------------------
11  |  abc  |   4589     |   09:05  |
11  |  abc  |   1234     |   09:04  |
10  |  xyz  |   0185     |   09:02  |
15  |  qpr  |   9564     |   08:54  |
```

so on...

Again, I can get the last two rows with id = 11; and, as far as all columns are not (null), it is returning "true" which is what I want literally.
But also I'd like to compare if their referances are the same or not; and, when I call the query, it has to return "true" or "false".

Thanks in advance

P.S. I actually just need a useful function or idea. I've already try to use inner join but couldnt manage it:

```
select table1.id, 
       table1.referance, 
       table2.id, 
       table2.referance 
from (select id, 
             referance, 
             row_number() 
             over (order by time desc) as seqnum 
      from mytable where id=':id') table1 
      inner join (select id, 
                         referance, 
                         row_number() 
                         over (order by time desc) as seqnum 
                  from mytable where id=':id') table2 
      on table1.referance != table2.referance 
al where seqnum <= 2 order by seqnum
```

Comment: To avoid confusion when reading the answers, keep in mind that your spelling of `reference` is incorrect. This is likely a mistake in the table-creation script, but it could trip you up later on...

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate your current query over the `id` and check if the two reference values be the same or not.

```
select
    id,
    case when count(distinct reference) = 1
         then 'true' else 'false' end as result
from
(
    select id, reference,
        row_number() over (order by time desc) as seqnum
    from table
    where id=':id'
) al
where seqnum <= 2
group by id;
```

If the distinct count of `reference` over the two records be `1` then it implies that they have the same value.  Otherwise, we can assume that the values are different.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `row_nubmer()`?  You can get the last two rows as:

```
select top 2 id, referance 
from mytable
where id=':id'
order by time desc;
```

You can then determine if these are the same using aggregation:

```
select (case when min(reference) <> max(reference) then 'false'
             else 'true'
        end) as is_same
from (select top 2 id, referance 
      from mytable
      where id=':id'
      order by time desc
     ) t;
```

Note:  This doesn't take `NULL` values for `reference` into account, but that is easily incorporated into the logic.